# Wi-Fi works with boot to windows but not Ubuntu

Tags: networking, dual-boot, iwlwifi

I am running :Description:  Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

I have two new Beelink SEI computers. I've setup both to dual boot windows 11 and Ubuntu. One has Wi-Fi working, the other has no wi-fi with Ubuntu (but it does in Windows). This is my network hardware on the unit which does not work. I've tried everything I can find online including installing drivers from the Intel site. But in settings Wi-Fi it still says "No Wi-Fi adapter found".
output from `lshw -C network`

```
*-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 30
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:19 memory:6001124000-6001127fff
```

---

The hardwired network works fine but I would rather use Wi-Fi.

-- as requested this is the output from dmesg

```
[    2.780800] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.785297] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.785316] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    2.786778] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 72.daa05125.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.862869] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX101, REV=0x351
[    2.987352] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected RF HR1 B3, rfid=0x10c000
[    4.000417] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[    4.001547] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    4.001549] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
[    4.001553] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 72.daa05125.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode
[    4.001556] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[    4.001559] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000022F0 | trm_hw_status0
[    4.001561] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[    4.001563] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CC13E | branchlink2
[    4.001565] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004C25DE | interruptlink1
[    4.001567] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004C25DE | interruptlink2
[    4.001569] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CADF8 | data1
[    4.001570] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | data2
[    4.001572] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[    4.001574] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[    4.001576] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0010CA3C | tsf low
[    4.001578] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[    4.001579] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[    4.001581] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x001125FA | time gp2
[    4.001583] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[    4.001585] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | uCode version major
[    4.001587] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | uCode version minor
[    4.001589] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000351 | hw version
[    4.001591] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x18C89001 | board version
[    4.001592] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8002FC12 | hcmd
[    4.001594] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00020000 | isr0
[    4.001596] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[    4.001598] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08F00002 | isr2
[    4.001600] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C0000C | isr3
[    4.001601] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[    4.001603] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[    4.001605] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CADF8 | wait_event
[    4.001606] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[    4.001608] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[    4.001610] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[    4.001612] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[    4.001613] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000B | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    4.001615] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[    4.001616] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000020 | flow_handler
[    4.001667] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    4.001669] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 7
[    4.001671] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[    4.001673] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    4.001675] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80455E9C | umac branchlink2
[    4.001677] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8047257E | umac interruptlink1
[    4.001679] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0081550 | umac interruptlink2
[    4.001681] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | umac data1
[    4.001682] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0081550 | umac data2
[    4.001684] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[    4.001686] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | umac major
[    4.001688] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | umac minor
[    4.001689] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x001125F8 | frame pointer
[    4.001691] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F18 | stack pointer
[    4.001693] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00010C00 | last host cmd
[    4.001695] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000004 | isr status reg
[    4.001723] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[    4.001725] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM error/state
[    4.001753] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00005636 | IML/ROM data1
[    4.001764] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[    4.001771] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    4.001792] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    4.001796] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    4.001818] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00090006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    4.001822] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A482 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    4.001843] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    4.001847] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    4.001869] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    4.001873] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000501 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    4.001894] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    4.001900] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000501 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    4.001924] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    4.001947] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    4.378395] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[    4.391381] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 0
[    4.398520] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX101, REV=0x351
[    5.532302] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[    5.533413] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    5.533416] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
[    5.533418] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 72.daa05125.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode
[    5.533420] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[    5.533422] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000022F0 | trm_hw_status0
[    5.533423] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[    5.533425] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CC13E | branchlink2
[    5.533426] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004C25DE | interruptlink1
[    5.533427] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004C25DE | interruptlink2
[    5.533429] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CADF8 | data1
[    5.533430] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | data2
[    5.533431] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[    5.533433] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[    5.533434] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0010BDB9 | tsf low
[    5.533435] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[    5.533437] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[    5.533438] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00111913 | time gp2
[    5.533439] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[    5.533441] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | uCode version major
[    5.533442] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | uCode version minor
[    5.533444] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000351 | hw version
[    5.533445] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x18C89001 | board version
[    5.533446] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8002FC12 | hcmd
[    5.533448] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00020000 | isr0
[    5.533449] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[    5.533450] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08F00002 | isr2
[    5.533452] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C0000C | isr3
[    5.533453] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[    5.533454] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[    5.533456] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CADF8 | wait_event
[    5.533457] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[    5.533458] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[    5.533460] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[    5.533461] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[    5.533462] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000B | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    5.533463] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[    5.533465] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000020 | flow_handler
[    5.533510] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    5.533511] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 7
[    5.533513] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[    5.533514] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    5.533516] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80455E9C | umac branchlink2
[    5.533517] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8047257E | umac interruptlink1
[    5.533519] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0081524 | umac interruptlink2
[    5.533520] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | umac data1
[    5.533522] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0081524 | umac data2
[    5.533523] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[    5.533524] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | umac major
[    5.533526] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | umac minor
[    5.533527] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00111911 | frame pointer
[    5.533529] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887EFC | stack pointer
[    5.533530] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00010C00 | last host cmd
[    5.533531] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000004 | isr status reg
[    5.533559] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[    5.533560] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM error/state
[    5.533587] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00005692 | IML/ROM data1
[    5.533596] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[    5.533603] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    5.533606] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    5.533628] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    5.533631] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00090006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    5.533653] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A482 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    5.533656] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    5.533678] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    5.533681] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    5.533702] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000501 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    5.533705] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    5.533729] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000501 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    5.533752] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    5.533775] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    5.900149] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[    5.912332] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 1
[    5.918423] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX101, REV=0x351
[    7.260423] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[    7.261531] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    7.261533] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
[    7.261535] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 72.daa05125.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode
[    7.261536] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[    7.261537] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000022F0 | trm_hw_status0
[    7.261538] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[    7.261539] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CC13E | branchlink2
[    7.261540] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004C25DE | interruptlink1
[    7.261541] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004C25DE | interruptlink2
[    7.261542] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CADF8 | data1
[    7.261543] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | data2
[    7.261544] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[    7.261545] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[    7.261545] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00109726 | tsf low
[    7.261546] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[    7.261547] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[    7.261548] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0010F284 | time gp2
[    7.261549] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[    7.261550] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | uCode version major
[    7.261551] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | uCode version minor
[    7.261551] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000351 | hw version
[    7.261552] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x18C89001 | board version
[    7.261553] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8002FC12 | hcmd
[    7.261554] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00020000 | isr0
[    7.261555] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[    7.261556] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08F00002 | isr2
[    7.261557] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C0000C | isr3
[    7.261557] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[    7.261558] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[    7.261559] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CADF8 | wait_event
[    7.261560] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[    7.261561] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[    7.261562] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[    7.261562] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[    7.261563] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000B | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    7.261564] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[    7.261565] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000020 | flow_handler
[    7.261610] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    7.261611] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 7
[    7.261612] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[    7.261613] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    7.261614] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80455E9C | umac branchlink2
[    7.261614] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8047257E | umac interruptlink1
[    7.261615] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0081570 | umac interruptlink2
[    7.261616] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | umac data1
[    7.261617] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0081570 | umac data2
[    7.261618] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[    7.261619] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | umac major
[    7.261619] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | umac minor
[    7.261620] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0010F282 | frame pointer
[    7.261621] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F00 | stack pointer
[    7.261622] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00010C00 | last host cmd
[    7.261623] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000004 | isr status reg
[    7.261656] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[    7.261656] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM error/state
[    7.261665] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00005694 | IML/ROM data1
[    7.261673] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[    7.261679] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    7.261682] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    7.261685] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    7.261687] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00090006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    7.261690] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A482 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    7.261693] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    7.261696] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    7.261699] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    7.261701] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000501 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    7.261704] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    7.261709] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000501 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    7.261714] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    7.261719] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    7.604383] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[    7.616345] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubunrtu.

Comment: When I run the same command (dmesg) on the computer which has a working Wi-Fi It shows a different hardware configuration. The working unit has Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x351.  But the non-working one had AX101. I don't see a driver for AX101 as a choice on the intel site for Ubuntu.

Comment: Is Fast Boot turned off in Windows? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: I saw that suggestion in one of the places I looked earlier.  The Windows version that computer is running is Windows 11 and I don't think it has a fast boot option (my Windows 10 machines do).

Comment: I believe it is called Fast Startup in W11: https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht513773-how-to-enable-or-disable-fast-startup-on-windows-11

Comment: This is the results from the Wifi script output suggested earlier in this post.  https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Y9y942fxnZ/

Comment: I turned off fast startup using the command window method described in the Lenovo link. No change.

Comment: What does this report" `ls /usr/lib/firmware | grep QuZ-a0-hr-b0` We might try renaming -72 so as to try an older or newer firmware. My 22.10 installation includes -71 and -73 but not -72.

Comment: Mine includes -71 and -72 but not -73. So what might that mean?

Comment: Lets download -73: `cd /usr/lib/firmware` and: `sudo wget  https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-73.ucode` Now rename -72: `sudo mv iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.bak` Reboot and show us: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: My uninformed opinion is that this doesn't look good:
[    2.767336] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.813842] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.815315] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.815336] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    2.816299] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 71.058653f6.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-71.ucode op_mode iwlmvm

Comment: It looks the same as before. Please try a live session of Ubuntu 22.10 which runs a later kernel version 5.19 to see if there is improvement.